# What is the relevance of weighted mean in daily life?

Tags: statistics

Weight of the subject tells what? Is it really applicable like this?

[image: Here what is the relevance of weighted mean?]

Comment: Generally universities use weights when calculating averages (mine does at least) because not all courses have the same work loads/ time commitments. If one person picked all courses that had smaller workloads (and so is 'easier'), would it be fair to compare his average mark to someone that did all the more intensive classes?

Comment: The University could simply want to bias their selections in a certain direction. They want students with all-around good grades, but given two students with the same grades in all other areas, they're more interested in someone who's top of their English or Economics class than someone who speaks Hindi. The students they want to attract most are those who will go on to publish important papers or take on important positions etc, bringing prestige.